# How compilation and linking at runtime is happening?

Tags: compilation, linker, runtime

In a tutorial I've encountered a new concept (for me), that I never thought is possible. Actually, I thought that compilation is an entirely pre-run-time process. This is the phrase from tutorial: "Compile time occurs before link time (when the output of one or more compiled files are joined together) and runtime (when a program is executed). In some programming languages it may be necessary for some compilation and linking to occur at runtime".

My questions are:

1. Is pre-run-time compilation and linking processes absolutely different from run-time compilation and linking? If yes, please explain the main differences.
2. How are code sections that need to be compiled(linked) during run-time marked and where is that information kept? (This may be different from language to language, if possible, please give a specific example).

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Runtime compilation

The best (most well known) example I'm personally aware of is the [just in time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) used by Java. As you might know Java code is being compiled into bytecode which can be interpreted by the Java Virtual Machine. It's therefore different from let's say C++ which is first fully (preprocessed) compiled (and linked) into an executable which can be ran directly by the OS without any virtual machine.

The Java bytecode is instead interpreted by the VM, which maps them to processor specific instructions. That being said the JVM does JIT, which takes that bytecode and compiles it (during runtime) into machine code. Here we arrive at your **second question**. Even in Java it can depend on which JVM you are using but basically there are pieces of code called **hotspots**, the pieces of code that are run frequently and which might be compiled so the application's performance improves. This is done during runtime because the normal compiler does not have (or well might not have) all the necessary data to make a proper judgement which pieces of code are in fact ran frequently. Therefore JIT requires some kind of **runtime statistics** gathering, which is done parallel to the program execution and is done by the **JVM**. What kind of statistics are gathered, what can be optimised (compiled in runtime) etc. depends on the implementation (you obviously cannot do everything a normal compiler would do due to memory and time constraints - guess this partly answers the **first question**? you don't compile everything and usually only a limited set of *optimisations* are supported in runtime compilation). You can try looking for such info but from my experience usually it's very badly documented and hard to find (at least when it comes to official sources, not presentations/blogs etc.)

### Runtime linking

Linker is a different pair of shoes. We cannot use the Java example anymore since it doesn't really have a *linker* like C or C++ (instead it has a *classloader* which takes care of loading files and putting it all together).

Usually linking is performed by a linker after the compilation step (static linking), this has pros (no dependencies) and cons (higher memory imprint as we cannot use a shared library, when the library number changes you need to recompile your sources).

Runtime linking (dynamic/late linking) is actually performed by the **OS** and it's the OS linker's job to first load shared libraries and then attach them to a running process. Furthermore there are also different types of dynamic linking: explicit and implicit. This has the benefit of not having to recompile the source when the version number changes since it's dynamic and library sharing but also drawbacks, what if you have different programs that use the same library but require different versions (look for **DLL hell**). So yes those two concepts are also quite different.

Again how it's all done, how it's decided what and how should be linked, is OS specific, for instance Microsoft has the [dynamic-link library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) concept.